# How to measure the performance of an mlr3 model in R?

Tags: r, mlr3

I was wondering how to measure the performance of prediction (using the test dataset) of an `mlr3` model? For example, if I create a knn model using `mlr3` like so:

```
library("mlr3")
library("mlr3learners")
 
# get data and split into training and test
aq <- na.omit(airquality)
train <- sample(nrow(aq), round(.7*nrow(aq))) # split 70-30
aqTrain <- aq[train, ]
aqTest <- aq[-train, ]


# create model
aqT <- TaskRegr$new(id = "knn", backend = aqTrain, target = "Ozone")
aqL <- lrn("regr.kknn")
aqMod <- aqL$train(aqT)
```

I can measure the mean square error of the model predictions doing something like:

```
prediction <- aqL$predict(aqT)
measure <- msr("regr.mse")
prediction$score(measure)
```

But how do I incorporate the test data into this? That is, how do I measure the performance of predictions on the test data?

In the previous version of `mlr` I could do something like; get the predictions using the test dataset and measure the performance of, say, the MSE or Rsquared values like so:

```
pred <- predict(aqMod, newdata = aqTest)
performance(pred, measures = list(mse, rsq))
```

Any suggestions as to how I can do this in `mlr3`?

Comment: You can do this in much the same way in mlr3, see [the relevant chapter of the mlr3 book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/train-predict.html).

Comment: Having read that chapter of the book, it tells me I should do something like: `
prediction = aqL$predict(aqT, row_ids = testRows)` where, `testRows` are the indices of the rows in the training data. However, this produces an error: 

`Error: DataBackend did not return the queried rows correctly: 33 requested, 17 received`

Comment: You should also be able to use `newdata` in the same way as for mlr.

Comment: There are a lot of examples in the linked manual. Usually you want to use cross-validation for unbiased performance estimates.

Comment: You either need to pass the complete task and work with row IDs for train/test, or split the data beforehand and work with `newdata`.

Answer (score 1):

You should trying this code

```
pred <- aqMod$predict_newdata(aqTest)
pred$score(list(msr("regr.mse"),
                   msr("regr.rmse")))
```